# "Double counting" using spherical coordinate

Tags: calculus

The question is to compute volume enclosed by $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=2z(x^2+y^2)$. I convert this to spherical coordinate as $r(\theta)=2 \sin^2 (\theta) \cos(\theta)$. I compute the following integral:
$$V=\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=0}^{2 \sin^2 (\theta) \cos(\theta)}r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta$$

This turns out to be mistake since correct integral interval for $\theta$ is from $0$ to $\pi/2$. What happened seems to be that $r(\theta)$ starts repeating after $\pi/2$.

My question is if there is any way to prevent this type of mistake other than actually plotting $r(\theta)$? That is, how to determine the point after which a polar/spherical curve starts to repeat itself.

Comment: Are you certain that spherical coordinates is the way to go? Did you consider cylindrical coordinates? Seeing $x^2+y^2$, but with $z$ treated differently makes me think it should at least be attempted.

Comment: @Arthur So long as I correct the integration interval for $\theta$ to 0 to $\pi/2$, the answer is correct and quite easy to compute. The thing is how to see this easily.

Answer (score 2):

From $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=2z(x^2+y^2)$ we have $$z={(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\over 2(x^2+y^2)}>0$$which means $$z>0\implies r\cos \theta>0\implies \cos\theta>0 \implies0\le \theta<{\pi\over 2}$$

Comment: This works in this particular case but in general this does not guarantee that $0\le \theta<\pi/2$ is correct integration interval. How do you know it does not repeat after say $\pi/4$ or $\pi/8$.

Comment: This is because the bound $2\sin^2\theta \cos \theta$ cannot be $< 0$. Also it does not matter whether $\theta <{\pi\over 4}$ or $\pi\over 8$ as long as the bounds are legal.